# Can't define a glyph as a word constituent

Tags: syntax-table

I'd like Emacs to treat this

dollar$sign

as one word. So I evaluated this line

(modify-syntax-entry ?$ "w")

to have Emacs treat dollar sign as a word constituent rather than a symbol. However, when I run forward-word from the beginning of the line below, it stops at the dollar sign when I'd like it to stop at the "n" instead.

dollar$sign

How can I define dollar sign as a word constituent and have forward-word ignore it just like when it sees alphabet?

Comment: Maybe you already have it configured correctly, and your problem is the behavior of `forward-word`.  Place your cursor immediately before the dollar sign, and type `C-u C-x =` and see what it says about the **syntax** of the character **$**.  In `fundamental-mode`, for example, the default **syntax** is already set to:  `syntax: w  which means: word`

Comment: It says "$ w which means: word".